# Compactness in sequence spaces.

Tags: real-analysis

We have the set $A = \{(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty} \in X : n^2\cdot \lvert x_n \rvert ^3 \leq 1 \}$. The question is to determine whether it is compact when $X=l_1$ and $X=l_2$ with their own metrics. In general, $l_p=\{(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty} : \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\lvert x_n \rvert ^p < \infty \}$ and the metric is $d_p=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\lvert x_n - y_n \rvert ^p$.

We proved a theorem in class about compactness in this space:

$A$ is compact in $l_p$ if and only if it is closed, bounded and for every $\epsilon >0$ there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}\lvert x_n \rvert ^p \leq \epsilon ^p$ for every $x=(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}\in A$.

I do not know how to determine whether this set is closed or not in these spaces. For example in the space of all sequences $\omega$ with the Frechet metric, I would check the coordinate-wise convergence. But, I am not sure it is true in these spaces. Secondly, I believe boundedness just trivial because we have inequality already. Lastly, to check the condition in the theorem, I could not do much because my knowledge and calculation skills are not good in terms of infinite sums. Can you help me with this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set is compact in $\ell^{p}$ if $p >1.5$ and not compact if $p \leq 1.5$. Closedness follows from the fact that convergence in any $\ell^{p}$ implies convergence of each coordinate.

For $p >1.5$ we have $ \sum\limits_{n=N}^{\infty} |x_n|^{p} \leq \sum\limits_{n=N}^{\infty} \frac 1 {n^{2p/3}}$ and the series $\sum\limits_{n=N}^{\infty} \frac 1 {n^{2p/3}}$ is convergent because $2p/3 >1$. Hence the conditions for compactness are satisfied.

When $ p\leq 1.5$ consider the elements $\left(1,\frac 1 {2^{2/3}},\frac 1 {3^{2/3}},...\frac 1 {N^{2/3}},0,0,0, \ldots \right)$, $N=1,2,...$.  If this sequence has  a convergent subsequence then the limit has to be $\left(\frac 1 {n^{2/3}} \right)$ but this sequence does not belong to $\ell^{p}$.

Comment: I am sorry, English is not my native language, so I couldn't understand what do you mean by "the limit has to bet" in your last sentence. Can you explain that sentence?

Comment: Moreover, in the theorem that I stated it says "$\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}\lvert x_n \rvert ^p \leq \epsilon ^p$". How do we conclude this inequality from the fact that $\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2p/3}}$?

Comment: @MahmutEsatAkın If $\sum a_n$ converges then $\sum_{n>N} a_n \to 0$ as $N \to \infty$.